# AWS multiple scaling groups in single ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-security-group

I want to place some ECS services on two separate security groups.

Say services S1, S2 on security group SG1, and services S3, S4 on security group SG2.

One approach would be to place them on two separate ECS clusters.

However, I prefer to place them on the same ECS cluster.

So I thought of defining two austoscaling groups (ASG1, ASG2) on the cluster, in order to achieve that. This means that machines on ASG1 would be associated with SG1, and machines on ASG2 would beassociated with SG2.


My question is, how do I associate S1, S2 with the machines on ASG1, and S3, S4 with the machines on ASG2?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to do that.  What's the point of keeping it in one cluster at that point?  A cluster is a set of capacity, so if you want one of those sets to have different security groups, and it would only have tasks from 1 of the services, just make a second cluster?